# ValidationExpression Multiline TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I have a multiline TextBox and my validation expression avoid to enter < and > so the user cant enter < or >, but the think is that the validator fire when make a return because analize all the line instead each line, because is multiline. What could I do? Here is my expression, thanks!!!

```
TextBox1.ValidationExpression= "^((?!<|>).)*$"
```

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnTextChanged event to the textbox. Then in the method add this:

textBoxName.Text = Regex.Replace(textBoxName.Text, "(<[^<>]*>)+", "");

This Regex expression: (<[^<>]*>)+ will prevent greater and less than signs from being entered

Comment: Yes but I need to use it on the client not on the server...if u know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this....

TextBox1.ValidationExpression= "^((?!<|>).|\r\n)*$"

Its because \r\n represents end of line character in windows system and in case of multiple lines there in the text box it should be consedered in the validation expression.

Comment: I was trying before but not working the validator fires, dont know why? :(

Answer (score 0):

This is my regular expresion!!!

@"^((?!<|>)(\s|.))*$"

Answer (score 0):

Well I tested the regular expression and it worked with me for multiple line too.

use this "^((?!<|>).|\r\n)*$"

It will work.